# How to Output the pdf in fpdf with both 'I' and 'D' options which should download the file and Show pdf in browser?

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I have a form setup with fpdf which outputs the pdf

```
$pdf->Output($_POST["fname"].'.pdf','D');
```

But I also want it to show in browser. Something like this

```
$pdf->Output($_POST["fname"].'.pdf','D','I');
```

I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Comment: `$pdf->Output('I',$_POST["fname"]);`

Comment: Call `Output()` twice

Comment: calling output twice doesn't work